# Ion Auth/CodeIgniter Fatal Error: Undefined method Ion_auth::get_user() called

Tags: php, codeigniter, authentication, ion-auth

Receiving this fatal error when trying to access my planner.php and shared.php controllers. Any thoughts?

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Exception' with message 'Undefined method Ion_auth::get_user() called' in
/application/libraries/Ion_auth.php:88 Stack trace: #0 

/application/core/MY_Controller.php(50): Ion_auth->__call('get_user', Array) #1 

/application/core/MY_Controller.php(50): Ion_auth->get_user() #2 

/application/controllers/user/planner.php(9): Common_Auth_Controller->__construct() #3

/system/core/CodeIgniter.php(288): Planner->__construct() #4 /index.php(202): require_once('/Users/lrussell...') #5 {main} thrown in/application/libraries/Ion_auth.php on line 88
```

Library Extension I'm Using for Ion Auth:
http://jondavidjohn.com/blog/2011/01/scalable-login-system-for-codeigniter-ion_auth

Planner Controller:
http://pastie.org/private/wc1bq6eiqb9hn8iubwdgq

Shared Controller:
http://pastie.org/private/uj3ta8dw3jl7kqxizs9n1a

Ion_auth Library Line 88 Segment:
http://pastie.org/private/mhgwdzjyhatwsdrux4gqpa

CRUD Model:
http://pastie.org/private/m2nhfqzabdsx5eiz6xqupw

Events Model:
http://pastie.org/private/b6ksjoowl7wde9errow

Shared Model:
http://pastie.org/private/f741jfnf8o2l5oxphnrl5w

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Uhm, it happened to me the same exact thing. In the latest releases of this library, Ben Edmunds used php magic method `__call()` so that you don't have to call a model's method by using the regular syntax `$this->ion_auth_model->method()` but using instead `$this->ion_auth->method()`, as if it was a method belonging to the library.

But, actually, that method belongs to the model. So, if you go have a look at the model, you'll see that there's no `get_user()` method (nor is there in the library!), or at least in the version I talk about (the latest or the one just before. I downloaded a fresh copy one or two weeks ago).
I think there are some errors in the documentation he provided (though the overall work he did is awesome, kudos to Ben).

You can try using the `user()` model method, which should yield to the same result (it's the closer in functionality). So call `$this->ion_auth->user()` and see if that fits your needs.

**EDIT**

To clarify...  instead of this...

```
$this->end_user = $this->ion_auth->current()->row();
```

do this...

```
$this->end_user = $this->ion_auth->user()->row();
```

Comment: I can confirm this, and it directly relates to this recent commit to the library https://github.com/benedmunds/CodeIgniter-Ion-Auth/commit/ef733edb5ef396fec57fe363c5c8616506054c79

Comment: Yeah, so the version from the website benedmunds.com/ion_auth is older, and you have to download the files directly from github for them to work properly. Thanks for all of your help guys!